# swiftで多重配列の重複した要素をフィルターしたい

Tags: swift, xcode

こういった構造のデータの重複（"name"キー）をフィルターしたいのですが
for文等を使えば済むのは承知しております。
filter{}を使用して重複を除去したいと思います。
*重複した["name"]は最初に出現した要素を生きとします。*（質問者以外のものが付け加えました）

```
var itemList = [
    ["name":"いぬ","no":"0"],
    ["name":"ねこ","no":"1"],
    ["name":"きりん","no":"2"],
    ["name":"ねこ","no":"3"],
    ["name":"らくだ","no":"4"]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

正直、`filter()`を使って、どれだけプログラムが簡潔になったか、疑問ですが、いちおうこうなりました。

```
let itemList = [
    ["name":"いぬ","no":"0"],
    ["name":"ねこ","no":"1"],
    ["name":"きりん","no":"2"],
    ["name":"ねこ","no":"3"],
    ["name":"らくだ","no":"4"]
]

var nameList = [String]()
let filteredList = itemList.filter({(var member: [String: String]) -> Bool in
    if nameList.contains(member["name"]!) {
        return false
    } else {
        nameList.append(member["name"]!)
        return true
    }
})
print(filteredList)
```

> [["no": "0", "name": "いぬ"],
>   ["no": "1", "name": "ねこ"],
>   ["no": "2", "name": "きりん"],
>   ["no": "4", "name": "らくだ"]]

「これは循環参照になってるぞ！」など、識者から指摘を受けそうな不安があります。フィルタリングの条件が動的に変化しているので、それが`filter()`関数に適していると、私には思えません。すなおに`for`文を使ったほうが無難と思います。

---

一般論でお話ししますと、重複を解消するには、`Set`が有効です。以下、Playgroundで実行してみてください。

```
let nameList = ["きりん", "ねこ", "いぬ", "ねこ", "らくだ"]
let nameSet = Set(nameList)
```

> nameSet // {"きりん", "いぬ", "ねこ", "らくだ"}

Comment: Set(nameList)
このような書き方が出来るんですね！目からうろこです。
ありがとうございます。
重複した["name"]は最初に出現した要素を生きとします。
さてここからが問題で、重複した配列を削除したindexさえわかればあとはfilterなどでなんとかなりそうなのですが。どうしても効率のよい書き方が思いつかず....

Comment: @まかまやにゃんすけ 回答を更新しました。

Comment: 親切にありがとうございます！
シンプルで見やすいです。素晴らしい。